# In Corda, `unexpected task state` when running a flow

Tags: corda

I am running a flow and receive the following error message:

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Was expecting to find transaction set
>   on current strand: Thread[Mock node 1 thread,5,main]

And:

> Terminated by unexpected exception {} java.lang.AssertionError:
>   Unexpected task state (fiber parking or parked has no chance to to
>   call `park`): -2 at
>   co.paralleluniverse.fibers.RunnableFiberTask.park(RunnableFiberTask.java:213)
>   ~[quasar-core-0.7.9-jdk8.jar:0.7.9] at

What is the cause of this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue was caused by calling a custom lambda method from within my flow:

```
myMethod { 
    subflow(xyz) 
}
```

If the method is converted to a method without a lambda, the error disappears.

This is due to an issue in how Quasar serialises Kotlin lambdas.